# How to drag mutiple images from horizontal tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am New to Xcod
I am making application were user can select the image's from horizontal table view and should be able to drag them one by one?

I am jst able to drag one image ?

plz suggest me some tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll view with paging, it will definitely comp your requirement.